# Evaluation involving Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int_C (2xy^2 - 3)dx + (2x^2y+1)dy$

where C is the curve in the x-y plane determined by the trace  (straight lines) of the following points:

start: (1,-3) -> (4,0) -> (0,4) -> (2,1).  The direction of motion in the curve is counterclockwise.

I definitely understand that this involves the use of Green's theorem. I would proceed by closing the curve, finding the parametrization (of the closing path) and then finding $\int_{C} F \dot dr =  \int\int_R (Q_x - P_y)dA - \int_{C_1} F \dot dr$

The algebra is terrible.

Although it is really convenient that $Q_x - P_y =0 $, I'm trying to find a faster, more efficient way of solving $\int_{C_1} F \dot dr$

Comment: Note that if $F(x,y) = x^2y^2$ then $dF = 2xy^2 \ dx + 2x^2y \ dy$. So you can simplify your integral to 

$$\int_C dF -3 \ dx + 1 \ dy =  F(2,1) - F(1,-3) + \int_C -3 \ dx + 1 \ dy $$

There remaining integrals are also straight-forward and can be calculated from the end-points of $C$ alone.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks!